# How is React JS rendered?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, web-deployment, server-side-rendering, html-rendering

This might be a silly question, but after reading many documents, I am still not sure. I know there are 3 main types of rendering:

- Sever side rendering (render at request time)
- Client-side rendering (render on client side)
- Static site generation (render at build time)

I have some experience with Next JS, and I know you can choose which rendering type you want for a page in Next JS.

However, for **React JS**, from what I read here and there, it seems to be client-side render. But when I host a React webpage (say on S3), I would build it first and host the generated static contents on S3. Doesn't this mean React JS fall into the **static site generation** category? What is the "build action" doing anyway, and how is it different from rendering?

Answer (score -1):

When you write your code you more than likely seperate your concerns and components into different files.  With react you likely have a .js file for each component, you may also have a .css file etc etc.  This is great for organising workflow, but not idea for a production app.

When you "build" your project, react takes all these files and merges them together and optimises for fast page loading.  You are left with a build directory which contains the files ready for deployment.

Rendering happens as the page is loaded. It is the process of react determining what the UI will look like by checking what components need to be loaded and what state they are in.